# Objective- C delaying for loop run-time

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkannotation

I'm trying to write a for loop in objective-c that will display a bunch of annotation views, each of these annotation views will in turn create a custom callout view (just a `UIView` subclass) in the middle of the screen with a picture).

However, I want the user to be able to hold onto the callout view and pause the for loop (delay the loop from continuing until the user lets go of the screen) and when they let go of the screen, the for loop should continue and go to the next annotationView immediately.

Example Code:

```
-(void)displayAnnotation:(MKAnnotationView *)view
{
    // ..blah blah blah
    // ..display some UIView

    // ..delay a second before returning
}

-(void)displayAllAnnotations:(NSMutableArray *)arrayOfAnnotationViews
{
    for (id annotationView in arrayOfAnnotationViews)
    {
        [self displayAnnotation:annotationView]

        // <NEED CODE HERE>
        // <If user holds screen, pause this loop from continuing>
        // <If user lets go, continue loop immediately to next picture>
    }
}
```

Let me know if you need additional information.

Comment: You are going to need a different approach.  You can't use a simple for-loop as while it is executing user interaction can't happen.  You will need to schedule a repeating `NSTimer` and use that to move to the next annotation.  You can then detect touch up/down events and pause the progression

Comment: ... indeed: it's called event-driven programming. A recurring event is triggered by a timer. User interaction is triggered by touch events. Etc. You write code to respond to those events. You don't try to usurp the OS's overall event handling.

Comment: How would I pass in parameters into the NSTimer? Or rather.. how do I keep track of which part of the NSMutableArray I'm at? Is there a robust solution or do I just need some global int counter that keep track of where I'm at in the array?

Comment: You never need a global anything. At worst you'd use an instance variable. If you wanted to associate state with a timer you'd use its `userInfo`.

Comment: Awesome thanks.  One more question: Is there a way to make NSTimer more accurate for its fire time?  I know you can setTolerance but even that isn't too great.  How can I make the firings more precise?

Answer (score 1):

You can not use a for loop for this, because you are blocking the main thread while the for loop is executed. This means that your view will not receive the touch events until the end of the for loop.

I will suggest using dispatch_async instead. A rough example is:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject
@property (nonatomic) NSUInteger viewIdx;
@property (nonatomic) NSArray *arrayOfAnnotationViews;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL userIsTappingScreen;
@end

@implementation MyClass

-(void)displayAnnotation:(MKAnnotationView *)view
{
    // ..blah blah blah
    // ..display some UIView
}

-(void)continueIteration
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        MKAnnotationView *view = self.arrayOfAnnotationViews[self.viewIdx];
        [self displayAnnotation:view];
        self.viewIdx++;
        if (user is tapping the screen) {
            self.userIsTappingScreen = YES;
        }
        else {
            dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [self continueIteration];
            });
        }
    });
 }

 -(void)displayAllAnnotations:(NSMutableArray *)arrayOfAnnotationViews
 {
     self.viewIdx = 0;
     self.arrayOfAnnotationViews = arrayOfAnnotationViews;
 }

 // This method need to be called by your code when the user lifts the finger from the screen
 -(void)userHasSoppedTappingTheScreen
 {
    if (self.userIsTappingScreen) {
        [self continueIteration];
    }
 }

 @end
```

Answer (score -1):

For making delay try this:

```
double delayInSeconds = 1.0;
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    //code to be executed on the main queue after delay
});
```